# Mutate across multiple columns based on condition (length of unique values)

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I'm trying to create a function inside `mutate() + across()` that changes into factor any variable which has five or less unique values (or any arbitrary number) wit the idea of using later that factors to do some grouping. I think the logic of the function is correct but I'm getting some incorrect dimensions error (error in Spanish). For the sake of simplicity, I'm using the mtcars database.

```
mtcars %>%
    mutate(across(1:ncol(.), 
        function(x) {
                if_else(length(unique(x[,i]))<=5, 
            as.factor(x), 
          x)}
    ))

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = across(...)`.
x número incorreto de dimensiones
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Any help or advice will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we need `if/else` as `ifelse/if_else` requires all arguments to be of equal length. The `length(unique` expression returns a logical value of length 1 and this may break the condition.  Also, with `dplyr`, we can use `select-helpers` i.e. `everything()` to select all the columns

```
library(dplyr)
out <- mtcars %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), 
        function(x) {
                if(length(unique(x))<=5) 
            as.factor(x) else  
          x}
    ))
```

-output

```
> str(out)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : Factor w/ 3 levels "4","6","8": 2 2 1 2 3 2 3 1 1 2 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ am  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ gear: Factor w/ 3 levels "3","4","5": 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```

---

In addition, the lambda function can be concise with `~` and make use of `n_distinct`

```
mtcars %>% 
   mutate(across(everything(), 
        ~ if(n_distinct(.x) <=5) as.factor(.x) else .x))
```

Comment: I totally forgot everything() and I also see x[,i] index wasn't necessary. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AlejandroCarrera yes, it is a for each loop

Comment: I appreciate you took my code as starting point and make the necessary improvements. Also you suggested and aditional and useful approach. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be to use a predicate function in `where` inside `across`.

We can either define a custom function:

```r
library(dplyr)

few_unique_vals <- function(x) {
  length(unique(x))<=5
}

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(across(where(few_unique_vals), as.factor)) %>%
  glimpse # for better printing

#> Rows: 32
#> Columns: 11
#> $ mpg  <dbl> 21.0, 21.0, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, 24.4, 22.8, 19.2, 17.8,~
#> $ cyl  <fct> 6, 6, 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8,~
#> $ disp <dbl> 160.0, 160.0, 108.0, 258.0, 360.0, 225.0, 360.0, 146.7, 140.8, 16~
#> $ hp   <dbl> 110, 110, 93, 110, 175, 105, 245, 62, 95, 123, 123, 180, 180, 180~
#> $ drat <dbl> 3.90, 3.90, 3.85, 3.08, 3.15, 2.76, 3.21, 3.69, 3.92, 3.92, 3.92,~
#> $ wt   <dbl> 2.620, 2.875, 2.320, 3.215, 3.440, 3.460, 3.570, 3.190, 3.150, 3.~
#> $ qsec <dbl> 16.46, 17.02, 18.61, 19.44, 17.02, 20.22, 15.84, 20.00, 22.90, 18~
#> $ vs   <fct> 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,~
#> $ am   <fct> 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,~
#> $ gear <fct> 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3,~
#> $ carb <dbl> 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2,~
```

Or we can use an anonymous purrr-style function:

```r
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(across(where(~ length(unique(.x))<=5),
                as.factor)) %>%
  glimpse # for better printing

#> Rows: 32
#> Columns: 11
#> $ mpg  <dbl> 21.0, 21.0, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, 24.4, 22.8, 19.2, 17.8,~
#> $ cyl  <fct> 6, 6, 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8,~
#> $ disp <dbl> 160.0, 160.0, 108.0, 258.0, 360.0, 225.0, 360.0, 146.7, 140.8, 16~
#> $ hp   <dbl> 110, 110, 93, 110, 175, 105, 245, 62, 95, 123, 123, 180, 180, 180~
#> $ drat <dbl> 3.90, 3.90, 3.85, 3.08, 3.15, 2.76, 3.21, 3.69, 3.92, 3.92, 3.92,~
#> $ wt   <dbl> 2.620, 2.875, 2.320, 3.215, 3.440, 3.460, 3.570, 3.190, 3.150, 3.~
#> $ qsec <dbl> 16.46, 17.02, 18.61, 19.44, 17.02, 20.22, 15.84, 20.00, 22.90, 18~
#> $ vs   <fct> 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,~
#> $ am   <fct> 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,~
#> $ gear <fct> 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3,~
#> $ carb <dbl> 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2,~
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>